# Mixed Content with heroku server

Tags: reactjs, laravel, ssl, heroku, lumen

Having this client-side configuration (react based)

```
export const config = {
  API_URL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://myserverapp.herokuapp.com/' : 'http://mywebapp/'
}
```

When deploying it to the server (some shared hosting server) and sending the requests to my backend server (lumen based on heroku server) I get this error -

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebapp.com/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://myserverapp.herokuapp.com/items'. This request has been blocked;
>   the content must be served over HTTPS.

- at the beginning the app was build by Angular and all works great! Now when switching to react this error happens.

What is happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: On an https webpage you can only make AJAX request to https webpage, I guess your code is running in production in "development" mode, did you check that it runs in "production" mode?

Comment: @NirBen-Yair hi yes, it does run at production mode. I know this because I set some conditions for production/development mode and all act as expected

Comment: does your "mywebapp" app runs on https?

Comment: @NirBen-Yair yes it does

Comment: well, your API request, for some reason is to ```http://myserverapp.herokuapp.com/items``` it should be to https

Comment: @NirBen-Yair yes, this what I can't figure up

Comment: In my cases, everything was alright, I just turned off and on the toggle button of "Heroku Hobby" and it started working

Answer (score 2):

Dropping this Comment for future users who fall into this issue

Error is caused by trying to load an insecure script "HTTP" from a secured URL "HTTPS"

## Fix 1

One way to fix the issue will be to visit the insecure version of the site (i.e) http://whatever.herokuapp.com but this isn't a good fix cause your viewers won't know what the issue is which brings us to Fix 2

## Fix 2

Get the URL to determine what protocol the very instance is making use of
In PHP, i did this using this lines of code

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on'){ $protocol = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; } else{ $protocol='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; }
```

and then appending the protocol to what ever you are importing from your website

If the import is from an external website, just replace http in your `script` tag or `style` tag with `https`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can just go for:

```
'//myserverapp.herokuapp.com/'
```

If you do want to write the protocol and still avoid mixed content, use:

```
location.protocol + '//myserverapp.herokuapp.com/'
```